# File Upload to Servlet with Ajax

Tags: jquery, servlets

I'm kind of confused on how to approach this. I'm uploading a file to a servlet immediatly after the user selects the file. The servlet then reads the file, and fills out the form. I'm having trouble with the uploading part. I'm going to list what I did step by step so that hopefully you can follow, and find any problems on the way. I am following this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html

I first had to tackle how to set the enctype="multipart/form-data" with an ajax request. I was able to fix that by using setRequestHeader. My JS became:

```
$.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "GenerateServlet",  
            data: "button="+filename,
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');},
            success: function(jsonResponse) {fillTemplate(jsonResponse);},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(jqXHR+" - "+textStatus+" - "+errorThrown);}  
            });
```

Okay cool I solved that, now I created the processRequest function. However, it's not being called. My doPost method was called so I know it's at least running the request I made.

From here I'm not sure if I'm missing something in my servlet, or my ajax request is wrong.
I tried adding:

```
@WebServlet(name = "FileUploadServlet", urlPatterns = {"/upload"})
@MultipartConfig
```

However, eclipse could not recognize their type.

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I thought the processRequest method was automatically called by the servlet when a file was uploaded. I'm an idiot.